# Does this sentence make sense grammatically?

Tags: grammaticality

> Humans on Mars has always been a favorite subject of sci-fi.

Or would it be...

> Humans on Mars have always been a favorite subject of sci-fi.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

They both make sense.

In the first sentence, "Humans on Mars" is a single concept, so a singular verb is appropriate.

In the second sentence, "Humans on Mars" is treated as a collection of people, so the plural verb can be used.

I think the second sentence sounds more natural because when you hear the plural word "humans", you're primed for a plural verb. When you then hear the singular verb you have to backtrack and reinterpret the noun phrase.

You can avoid this problem by rearranging the sentence:

> One of the most popular subjects of sci-fi has been humans on Mars.

Answer (score 0):

"Humans on Mars has always been a favorite subject of sci-fi" is correct.
'Humans on Mars' is your subject/what you're referring to, and that subject is singular, since you're talking about a single group/concept of interest in sci-fi. So, that means you'd use the word "has" :-)